# Linux distro for acer 4741G laptop

Tags: linux, xorg, backtrack

I need to install linux for my acer 4741 laptop.

Anyone who did this before and managed to solve the device
driver problems please share your experience with me.

I already installed the backtrack linux and I able to make 
it work the both wireless and wired network connections and 
also the sound card is also working. But the problem is that
I unable to configure 1360x768 resolution of the display.
The display looking really flat and ugly under that linux.
some help ? can you guide how to correctly configure the 
/etc/X11/xorg.conf ?

--Thanks in advance--

Answer (score 0):

First backup your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

```
# cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/backup_xorg.conf
```

Then edit the xorg.conf file with vi and add a monitor resolution value to it like.

```
# vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Note:if you are not confortable with `vi` you can edit using your text editor and save it as /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Then in the section "Screen" add your resolution,it will usually like

```
Section "Screen"
   Identifier    "Default Screen"
   Device    "VirtualBox graphics card"
   Monitor    "Configured Monitor"
DefaultDepth    24
   SubSection "Display"
         Depth     24
         Modes     "1360x768"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Make sure you are editing the correct vendor details.
you need to specify your resolution mode as 1360x768 and you are done.

Then restart the XServer by pressing `control+alt+backspace` together.